# how make a one2one relation without duplicated? openerp 7

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

So ...... suppose I have class "person" and "color". How to make it so if one 
color is assigned to a person ... it can not be assigned to other person

```
class person(osv.Model):
    _name = 'person'

    _columns = {            
            'name': fields.char('Person', size=50, help="Persona"), 
            'color_p : fields.one2one('colors','Color'),
                }
person()

class colors(osv.Model):
    _name = 'colors'

    _columns = {            
            'name': fields.char('Color', size=50, help="Color"),           
                }
colors()
```

Answer (score 0):

For OpenERP 7 you can try to use `_inherits` (see for example http://dirtyhandsphp.blogspot.in/2014/10/openerp-one2one-relational-field-example.html).

However, I've needed to set a one2one relationship in the past and this solution wasn't as succesful as I had expected. May be you think different ;)

Comment: i tried that link before bur i did not uderstand i need an example more expecific, thanks for helping

Comment: That answer should work, replace one2one with many2one and then, in the person class:
     _inherits = {'colors': "color_id"}

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 models and you want to create a one2one relationship:

```
class ServiceLine(models.Model):
    _name = "service.line"

    title = fields.Char(string='Title')
    service_cost = fields.Float(string='Cost', track_visibility='onchange')


class ServiceExample(models.Model):
    _name = "service.example"

    _description = "My Awesome Singular Service Example"

    _inherits = {
        'service.line': 'service_line_id',
    }

    service_line_id = fields.Many2one(
        'service.line', string='Service Line ID', required=True, ondelete='cascade', unique=True, auto_join=True
    )

    service_example_details = fields.Char(string='Details', track_visibility='onchange')
```

This will make the magic! Now you can use any field of your one2one relationship in your service_example model:

```
service_example_record = self.env['service.example'].create({
  'title': 'My Awesome Service',
  'service_cost': 50.5,
  'service_example_details': 'My Awesome Details Service...'
})
```